# jQuery cloning issue for html elements

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to clone HTML element(Text box) & its working fine with jQuery 1.4.2 but in my project i am using jQuery 1.9.1 .

The problem is that, In jQuery 1.9.1 it also clone the value of the text box even if value set to null.

here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BE5Lr/1/):

```
var i = 1;
$("button").click(function() {
  $("table tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).attr({
      'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
      'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
      'value': ''               
    });
  }).end().appendTo("table");
  i++;
});
```

Thank You.

Comment: I would say your problem probably has to do with the change in `.attr` vs [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) (which was added in 1.6.x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `prop()` instead of `attr()`, if using latest jquery (1.6+) ..

> For example, selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked, and defaultSelected should be retrieved and set with the .prop() method. Prior to jQuery 1.6, these properties were retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the scope of attr. These do not have corresponding attributes and are only properties.

try this

```
var i = 1;
$("button").click(function() {
  $("table tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
   $(this).prop({
    'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
    'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
    'value': ''               
  });
}).end().appendTo("table");
i++;
});
```

or instead of chaging an attribute `value` using `attr()` use `.val('')`

```
var i = 1;
$("button").click(function() {
  $("table tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
   $(this).attr({
    'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
    'name': function(_, name) { return name + i }
  }).val('');
}).end().appendTo("table");
i++;
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BE5Lr/2944/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the value instead of using value attribute

```
var i = 1;
$("button").click(function() {
    $("table tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
        $(this).attr({
            'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
            'name': function(_, name) { return name + i }
        }).val('');
    }).end().appendTo("table");
    i++;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZACYJ/)